# How to use DateComponents to represent the extra 1 hour period at the end of day light saving?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, nsdate

Usually, during end of day light saving, we will be gaining extra 1 hours.

Take Tehran timezone as an example.

> During 22 September 2021, Tehran will backward by 1 hour from 00:00
> AM, to 11:00 PM.

I wrote the following code to demonstrate such.

```
import UIKit

func date(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int, second: Int) -> Date {
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = year
    dateComponents.month = month
    dateComponents.day = day
    dateComponents.hour = hour
    dateComponents.minute = minute
    dateComponents.second = second

    let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
    return date
}

// During 22 September 2021, Tehran will backward by 1 hour from 00:00 AM, to 11:00 PM.

let tehranTimeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Tehran")!
let oldDefault = NSTimeZone.default
NSTimeZone.default = tehranTimeZone
defer {
    NSTimeZone.default = oldDefault
}


let date1 = date(year: 2021, month: 09, day: 21, hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59)
let date2 = date(year: 2021, month: 09, day: 22, hour: 00, minute: 00, second: 00)
let date3 = date(year: 2021, month: 09, day: 22, hour: 00, minute: 00, second: 01)

// STEP 1: 2021 Sep 21 23:59:59 => 1632252599.0, Tuesday, September 21, 2021 at 11:59:59 PM Iran Daylight Time
print("STEP 1: 2021 Sep 21 23:59:59 => \(date1.timeIntervalSince1970), \(date1.description(with: .current))")

// STEP 2: 2021 Sep 22 00:00:00 => 1632256200.0, Wednesday, September 22, 2021 at 12:00:00 AM Iran Standard Time
print("STEP 2: 2021 Sep 22 00:00:00 => \(date2.timeIntervalSince1970), \(date2.description(with: .current))")

// STEP 3: 2021 Sep 22 00:00:01 => 1632256201.0, Wednesday, September 22, 2021 at 12:00:01 AM Iran Standard Time
print("STEP 3: 2021 Sep 22 00:00:01 => \(date3.timeIntervalSince1970), \(date3.description(with: .current))")
```

From STEP 1 transits to STEP 2, instead for their `timeIntervalSince1970` different by +1 seconds, their difference are +3601 seconds, due to the extra 1 hour gain.

Now, my question is, how can we use `DateComponents` to represent the extra 1 hour period at the end of day light saving?

**In another, how can I use `DateComponents` to generate a `Date` which is capable to print the following?**

```
2021 Sep 21 23:00:00 => 1632252600.0, Tuesday, September 21, 2021 at 11:00:00 PM Iran Standard Time
```

---

Now, we understand that, in Tehran, during 2021 Sept 21, there are 2 type of 23:00:00 time

- 23:00:00 Iran Daylight time (Epoch is 1632249000)
- 23:00:00 Iran Standard time (Epoch is 1632252600)

---

### 23:00:00 Iran Daylight time (Epoch is 1632249000)

[image]

I can represent the above using

```
let date = date(year: 2021, month: 09, day: 21, hour: 23, minute: 00, second: 00)
```

---

### 23:00:00 Iran Standard time (Epoch is 1632252600)

[image]

I have no idea how to represent the above. As, I do not find a way in `DateComponents`, to enable us to specific whether the local time is belong to standard time, or daylight time.

Answer (score 1):

`DateComponents` do not have a time zone. The time zone comes into it when you convert `DateComponents` to a `Date`, using the call `Calendar.date(from:)`. It's the calendar's time zone that determines how those `DateComponents` are converted to a `Date`.

Instead of using `Calendar.current`, create a custom calendar and set it to the IRST time zone. (I couldn't figure out the time zone for Iran Daylight time. I would have expected it to have the abbreviation "IRDT", but that doesn't work.)

Let's say we have a calendar `irstCalendar` that's set to Iran Standard Time ("IRST").

If you use `irstCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)` you'll always get the `Date` based on standard time.

Consider this code:

```
func date(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int, second: Int, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> Date {
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = year
    dateComponents.month = month
    dateComponents.day = day
    dateComponents.hour = hour
    dateComponents.minute = minute
    dateComponents.second = second

    let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
    return date
}

guard let tehranStandardTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "IRST") else {
    fatalError("Can't create time zones")
}

var tehranSTCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
tehranSTCalendar.timeZone = tehranStandardTimeZone

let tehranDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
tehranDateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
tehranDateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

tehranDateFormatter.timeZone = tehranStandardTimeZone
let date1 = date(year: 2021, month: 09, day: 21, hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59, calendar: tehranSTCalendar)
let date2 = date(year: 2021, month: 09, day: 22, hour: 00, minute: 00, second: 00, calendar: tehranSTCalendar)
let date3 = date(year: 2021, month: 09, day: 22, hour: 00, minute: 00, second: 01, calendar: tehranSTCalendar)

print("STEP 1: 2021 Sep 21 23:59:59 => \(date1.timeIntervalSince1970), \(tehranDateFormatter.string(from:date1))")
print("STEP 2: 2021 Sep 22 00:00:00 => \(date2.timeIntervalSince1970), \(tehranDateFormatter.string(from:date2))")
print("STEP 3: 2021 Sep 22 00:00:01 => \(date3.timeIntervalSince1970), \(tehranDateFormatter.string(from:date3))")
```

That outputs:

```
STEP 1: 2021 Sep 21 23:59:59 => 1632252599.0, Sep 21, 2021 at 11:59:59 PM
STEP 2: 2021 Sep 22 00:00:00 => 1632256200.0, Sep 22, 2021 at 12:00:00 AM
STEP 3: 2021 Sep 22 00:00:01 => 1632256201.0, Sep 22, 2021 at 12:00:01 AM
```

Comment: But, for step 1, isn’t the correct expectation should be 1632256199.0 instead of 1632252599.0 ? This is because after 1 second passed by, it shall be 1632256200.0